# What's the correct way to have a `backup` user who is able to read everything to create backups with rsnapshot?

Tags: linux, backup

I'd like to use rsnapshot to backup my local computer as well as two remote machines to a portable storage device. My plan was to use `rsnaphot` on the local machine, create a `backup` user on the remote machines, and let my local root access the `backup` account via ssh public keys. I didn't want to enable root login, I thought this might be a security feature.

So the problem starts: The remote backup user should be able to read as much as possible. How can I accomplish this? I could add this user to every existing group, this way he will be able to read every file which is group-readable. But this way, this user would also be able to write, delete, ... those files. Or I could change the group of every file to `backup` or some such, but of course this would be too invasive and by the way very insane.

Copy my local root's public key to the remote root account and enabling root login would be the easiest way, heh? Should I do it?

How is this done correctly?

Comment: Why not just create any user, and allow them only access to the program `rsnapshot` via the sudoers file? Append something like `backupuser ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsnapshot` (or wherever it installs, check with `which rsnapshot`).  Here is an [in-depth guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821) about the sudoers file that applies to more than just Ubuntu.  **Do not** do a root profile :D  (even locally, it's just bad practice)

Comment: This does not solve the problem I think, `sudo rsnapshot` will act as `root` and therefore use `root`s ssh keys, `sudo -u myusername` will use my keys, but be useless since I have `myusername`s access rights. Not easy to solve I think. By the way, on the remote machines I can use `root`, http://www.rsnapshot.org/howto/using-rsnapshot-and-ssh.html shows how to disable root login but allow root to execute commands when authenticated with keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://www.rsnapshot.org/howto/using-rsnapshot-and-ssh.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520111619/http://rsnapshot.org/howto/using-rsnapshot-and-ssh.html) *(Web Archive)* helped me a lot. I ended up with using `root` on the remote machines, and root as well on my local machine (via `sudo` of course).

The idea is to have several keys and to restrict the keys to certain commands. For example, I configured my remote host in a way which does not permit `root` login, but allows to execute a certain command (in my case I think it's rsync, I have to admit I just used the `validate-rsync` script as suggested in the linked document without thinking too much) if authenticated with public key. So even if someone *had* access to my local `root` account, the could not login directly (yes, he maybe could rsync corrupted files and some such, also corrupt the `allowed_keys` and so on).

At the moment, I think this is the best trade-off between usability and security.